# Get and show the FormArray values of reactive forms in a Div before submitting in POST Api

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```html
<div
  class="row"
  *ngFor="let mcq of mcqs().controls; let i = index;"
  [formGroupName]="i"
>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" class="w-100-p">
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput formControlName="question"> </textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" class="w-100-p">
      <mat-label>Answer</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput formControlName="answer"> </textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <input type="hidden" formControlname="question_type" />
    <input type="hidden" formControlname="_questionId" />
  </div>
</div>
```

From this FormArray i need to get values and show it in a DIV as a preview before posting to api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the values of your `FormArray`, you can access the `value` property. You can also put it into a `div` element, but I recommend using `pre` instead (it looks a bit nicer):

```html
<pre>{{ mcqs().value | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: i am getting object object... When i click a button the value which i entered need to show in a div

Comment: Sorry, I added the missing ingredient, which was the `json` pipe.

Comment: Thank u so much... Also can u guide me how to get particular array value

Comment: In general, you can index arrays with square brackets to access elements at various positions. Indexing starts from 0, so to get the first element of the array, you would use `mcqs().value[0]`, to get the second one, you would index with 1 and so on. Do you have any particular scenario?